# Getting 403 error when trying to make API call to the script deployed to Google Script

Tags: php, authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

There is a script deployed to Google Script which is bound to Google Cloud project and is published/deployed as API executable. All credentials from Google Cloud are in place.

```
public function runCreateDriveScript($clientName, $orderName)
{
    $scriptId = env('GOOGLE_SCRIPT_ID');
    $service = $this->getService();
    $request = new \Google_Service_Script_ExecutionRequest();
    $request->setFunction('main');
    $request->setParameters(["fdf"]);
    try {
        $response = $service->scripts->run($scriptId, $request);
        if ($response->getError()) {
            $error = $response->getError()['details'][0];
            printf("Script error message: %s\n", $error['errorMessage']);

            if (array_key_exists('scriptStackTraceElements', $error)) {
                print "Script error stacktrace:\n";
                foreach ($error['scriptStackTraceElements'] as $trace) {
                    printf("\t%s: %d\n", $trace['function'], $trace['lineNumber']);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // The API encountered a problem before the script started executing.
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }

}
```

> Caught exception: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The caller does not 
>   have permission", "errors": [ { "message": "The caller does not have 
>   permission", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": 
>   "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }

What am I missing? What should I do in order to call Google Script by API? Is there a good manual on that topic?

Comment: Could you please add the full error message?

Comment: Please see an update.

Comment: Have you authenticated with the scopes required by your script? Provide scopes using `Google_Client::setScopes()`. This document explains how to determine which scopes your script needs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes